# Batch file to configure WSUS in Workgroup

Tags: batch, workgroup, psexec, wsus

I'd like to create a Batch file that I can then remotely execute on machines in a workgroup in order to point them at a WSUS installation. I understand it is via the use registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUStatusServer
```

And then the following key set to 1:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

Then to run a wuauclt /reportnow and /detectnow.

Is this possible via batch? Can you create and edit registry keys via batch files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly use below commands to create batch file.

```
REM Stop the Automatic Updates service
net stop wuauserv

REM Stop the Windows Management Instrumentation service
net stop winmgmt

REM Backup ReportingEvents.log.  Then, delete the contents of
REM  %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution and
REM  %systemroot%\system32\WBEM\Repository
copy %systemroot%\softwaredistribution\reportingevents.log %homedrive%\
del /f /q %systemroot%\softwaredistribution\*.*
move %homedrive%\reportingevents.log %systemroot%\softwaredistribution

REM Delete SusClientID and AccountDomainSid keys from
REM  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate
SET WU_KEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate
reg delete %WU_KEY% /v SusClientID
reg delete %WU_KEY% /v AccountDomainSid
SET WU_KEY=

REM Start the Automatic Updates service
net start wuauserv

REM Start the Windows Management Instrumentation service
net start winmgmt

REM Force a group policy update
gpupdate /force

REM Roll the WU Client...
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow
```